# mysterious Union spark.sql.utils.AnalysisException in Spark 3.3.2, but not seeing in 3.4.0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am starting to see spark.sql.utils.AnalysisException w.r.t union when I upgraded the EMR setup to 6.11 (which uses spark 3.3.2) , the stacktrace seems to point to a code location where there is no union, also I have only unionByName everywhere in the codebase with allowMissingColumns set to True. I suspect the reported union in the exception is probably inserted in the plan internally by spark optimizer?

```
spark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Union can only be performed on tables with the same number of columns, but the first table has 7 columns and the second table has 6 columns
```

The issue seems to have disappeared when I did a quick test with spark 3.4.0 in my local setup, I am just curious if this is a known issue or if I am missing something.

Comment: When looking at the sql plan, the hidden _metadata#1628 (originating from delta table source) field gets added automatically by the plan although its not specified anywhere in my codebase, I suspect this is probably introduced by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-41538, but the issue is somehow not seen in 3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I got same error using this

```html
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkSQLExample").getOrCreate()
data1 = [("A", 1,3), ("B", 2,3), ("C", 3,5)]
columns1 = ["col1", "col2","col3"]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, columns1)
data2 = [("X", "Y")]
columns2 = ["col1", "col2"]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, columns2)
union_df = df1.union(df2)
union_df.show()
```

Because of difference in num of columns in two dfs
[image]

make sure to have same columns in two dfs you union

The unionByName operation in Spark SQL combines two DataFrames or tables by matching columns with the same names and compatible data types. However, it requires that the number of columns in both DataFrames is the same.

Based on the error message, it seems that you have a table (or DataFrame) with 7 columns and another table (or DataFrame) with 6 columns, and you're trying to perform a union between them using the unionByName operation. This is causing the error because the number of columns is not matching.

Comment: could you please share detail code for more reference

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not using using union anywhere, just using unionByName everywhere with allowMissingColumns set to True, which makes me believe thats its probably related to internally generated spark code. I have a couple of layers of transformation (mostly inner join / unionByName), but I am still trying to find a simplified version to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Also, I am seeing this exception only in Spark 3.3.2 not in the higher or lower versions.

Comment: could you add code details for me to check

Answer (score 0):

The workaround in 3.3.2 that I followed to avoid seeing the exception is to checkpoint the intermediate dataframe and break the sql plan lineage.
intermediate_df = (intermediate_df).localCheckpoint()

Spark 3.4.0 seems to also resolve the issue.